# Why does PHP assignment behave this way?

Tags: php

I thought PHP `=` was a simple value assignment. For example:

```
$x = 1;
$a = $x;
$b = $x;
$a++;
echo $a;
echo $b;
```

Produces `21` as expected. However, the below code behaves different then what I expected. I was basically trying to assign the "same" value to many variables:

```
class X {
    public $val = 0;

    public function doSomething() {
      $this->val = "hi";
    }
}

function someFunction() {
    $template = array('non_object' => 0, 'object' => new X());
    $a = $template;
    $b = $template;

    //Do something
    $a['object']->doSomething();

    var_dump($a);
    var_dump($b);
}
```

Produces:

```
array(2) {
  ["non_object"]=>
  int(0)
  ["object"]=>
  object(X)#1 (1) {
    ["val"]=>
    string(2) "hi"
  }
}
array(2) {
  ["non_object"]=>
  int(0)
  ["object"]=>
  object(X)#1 (1) {
    ["val"]=>
    string(2) "hi"
  }
}
```

As you can see the `object` property in `array A` changed as expected, but also changed in `array B`.

You can check the code here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bff611fc9854b777114d38a3b4c60d524fdf2e19

How can I assign the same value to many PHP variables and manipulate them without having them in this "quantum entanglement" state and without copying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of PHP 5, all objects are passed and assigned by reference

Take your code below

```
  $a = $template;
  $b = $template;
```

**Reason why you got the unexpected result:**

What exactly happens here is , `$a` and `$b` are just like 'pointers' or 'handlers' pointing to that same object `$template` and thats the reason you met something unexpected cos you changed the object through the one of the references `$a` and since `$b` also references the same object, you noticed the change

From PHP Manual **[Objects and References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)**

> One of the key-points of PHP5 OOP that is often mentioned is that
>   "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely
>   true. This section rectifies that general thought using some examples.
>
> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to
>   write to the same value. As of PHP5, an object variable doesn't
>   contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object
>   identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object.
>   When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another
>   variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of
>   the identifier, which points to the same object.

Answer (score 5):

You have assigned variable $a and $b with same object. So if you call `$a["object"]->doSomething()` or `$b["object"]->doSomething()` will give same result because `$a["object"]` and `$b["object"]` are same.

If you need outputs to be different, try below code:

```
class X {
    public $val = 0;

    public function doSomething() {
      $this->val = "hi";
    }
}

function someFunction() {
    $a = array('non_object' => 0, 'object' => new X());
    $b = array('non_object' => 0, 'object' => new X());

    //Do something
    $a['object']->doSomething();

    var_dump($a);
    var_dump($b);
}
```

Output will be as below :

```
array(2) {
  ["non_object"]=>
  int(0)
  ["object"]=>
  object(X)#1 (1) {
    ["val"]=>
    string(2) "hi"
  }
}
array(2) {
  ["non_object"]=>
  int(0)
  ["object"]=>
  object(X)#2 (1) {
    ["val"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Here you are assigning different object to $a an $b.

[Please check this](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign value only, u can use function: clone

```
class X {
    public $val = 0;

    public function increment() {
    $this->val += 1;
    }
}

function someFunction() {
    $template =new X();
    $a = $template;
    $b = clone $template;

    //Increment a
    $a->increment();

    var_dump($a);
    var_dump($b);
}

someFunction();

$x = 1;
$a = $x;
$b = $x;

$a++;
echo $a;
echo $b;
```

[check this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b19c1698dafcef89087785e0b573fea601032259)